# Can anyone explain, why the result was 400 instead of 200?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

#source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/
#Python Decorators

```
def decor1(func):
    def inner():
        x = func()
        return x * x
    return inner

def decor(func):
    def inner():
        x = func()
        return 2 * x
    return inner

@decor1
@decor
def num():
    return 10

print(num())
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `decor1(decor(num()))` - the decorators get called in reverse order of how they were applied, so 10 gets doubled before it's squared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an expected result,

```
decor1(decor(num())) # it's call like this.

decor >> return 10 *2 >> 20

decor1 >> return 20 * 20 >> 400
```

And I would suggest putting the print inside the decorator to identify the execution order.

```
<function decor at 0x113de8430>
10
<function decor1 at 0x113bfc430>
20
400
```

Answer (score 0):

***[Look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqTKF.png)***

**Step1**: num() is called

**Step2**: num is decorated so go to decor1() which is the main decor.

**Step3**: decor1 returns inner so go to inner() in decor1

**Step4**: inner assigns func to x. func is decor()

**Step5**: Go to decor()

**Step6**: decor returns inner so go to inner() in decor().

**Step7**: "inner" which is in the decor() assigns func to x func is num().

**Step8**: Go to num() num returns 10 so x which is in the decor() is assigned 10 and inner returns 20 (2*10)

**Step9**: x which is in the decor1() is assigned 20 and inner returns 400 (20*20)

Good Luck!

Comment: No images of code, please.